# When baking frozen pizza in oven

Tags: pizza, frozen

When baking frozen pizza, why do the edges burn but cheese in center is not fully melted.

Comment: without more details on your oven, the temperature you're baking at, where in the oven you're putting the pizza, how long you allow the oven to preheat, what you're putting the pizza on while baking, and exactly which frozen pizza you're baking, it is impossible for us to know.

Comment: Do you have a convection oven?  If so, look to see if the company has instructions for convection ovens, or turn the fan off

Answer (score 3):

If this is a bought frozen pizza then it is important to follow the instructions on the packet. Don't try to improve it or cut corners.

Also your oven may not have the temperature you want it to. Get hold of a thermometer and check it.

Answer (score 1):

I would try putting oven thermometer(s) in various places in your oven to see if the temperature is consistent. Ovens often have "hot spots" where the temperature is different.

Answer (score 0):

Frozen pizza tends to be baked directly on the rack.  Also, toppings are probably a little more heavily dispersed toward the center.  The edges have less protection from the toppings. Your edges cook more quickly because they are less protected by toppings.  You can reduce your oven temperature to reduce the overcooking.  If you really want to be meticulous about it you could place a large sheet of foil on your oven rack, then the pizza, then curl the foil over the edges of your pizza to offer protection from the heat.

Answer (score 0):

The company that makes the pizza spend quite a bit of money on food scientists, therefore I suggest following the instructions exactly. However, if that doesn't yield good results, you can try to defrost the pizza on top of an oiled baking container (e.g. big metal pan), and bake on it instead of directly on the rack. It could be that while the edge of the pizza are cooking, the centre parts are still melting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a mind reader or a chef or even a very good cook, but I would bet that if your edges are browning to quickly it's because it's to hot for too long. So if I were trying to figure out how to prevent that I would lower the temperature  but keep the time the same and see how that goes. I don't think it matters a whole lot really who makes the oven, what company makes the pizza. What time of day it is or if your oven is in direct sunlight while cooking whether you put the pizza on the top rack,bottom rack, cook it upside side down or even fold it in half and screw it to the side, just lower the temp and see what happens maybe you have to leave it in for a little longer. If that doesn't work, try something like lowering the temperature again and see what happens. And pay attention to what your doing so you know what works or doesn't work.